# VPS: this site can't be reached

Tags: iis, server, web-hosting, vps, administration

I purchased a VPS server, installed IIS, setup domain and published static index.html page. It worked if I go to mydomain.com but 1 or 1.5 hours later it stopped working and I can only see the message The site can't be reached.
The VPS is accessible via Remote desktop and if I locally run the IE I can access mydomain.com but It does not work from outside of the VPS.
If I reboot the VPS server then after a while the page can be accessed again but again it lasts for around 1-1.5hours.
What could be the reason of this?

Comment: looks to me like the DNS but slow, add a dns pointing to google (8.8.8.4) works but the VPS "goes to sleep" after 1.5 hours, look at the VPS configuration, you probably have a panel to manage it and see if it is mentioned this.

Comment: What method did you use to access? Domain name or IP address? Can you get more detailed message about this error? Such as its status code.

Comment: I am trying to access it via domain name: mydomain.com. I thought that maybe idle timeout of IIS could be the issue, so I changed it to 0 from 20, but it did not help. Initially the site (static html) works for about 20-30 mins and I especially do not make any request during this time, then I check and it says "This site can’t be reached". Firefox says: " PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR"

Comment: Chrome says : ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Answer (score 0):

If it is caused by idle timeout, then your index.html page will not be displayed, this error means that your browser cannot establish a connection with the website you try to reach, because your Internet connection has been interrupted or because your internet service provider has blocked the access to the website.

You can try the following methods to solve this error:

1. Restart your Internet Router.
2. Try to visit other websites, to make sure that your Internet connection is working.
3. If you own another computer/device in your place, then try to visit the website where your receive the "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" error, in order to make sure that the site you 're trying to visit is not blocked from your ISP.
4. If you have setup a VPN connection, then disconnect from it.
5. Temporarily disable the Firewall application.